# Coloring a route in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want some of my turtles to leave at trace of the steps they make. I want them to change the color of the patches they pass by on their move. Similar to what the "pen-down" command does - just with the effect, that the patches change color. It is esay for me to change the color of the patch, the turtle reach - but I want all the patches colored - like if you were walking on a lawn, and the grass under you momentaneouesly turns red :-) Nut just the steps with every tick, but the continous route.
Is there a way?  I would be glad to se a small coded example. Thanks very much - this homepage does a great job.
Magellancruiser

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I left an answer below that I hope was helpful.  You left a very good description of your problem, which is appreciated, but for future reference it's also preferable to try to post at least a little code showing what you've tried so far.  Good luck with your NetLogo model!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one basic solution.  The key is realizing that instead of having the turtle do something like `forward (random 10) + 1` you can instead have it go `forward 1` a number of times equal to `(random 10) + 1`.  Because the distances are based on path sizes (1 = 1 patch across), if you color the patches as you go `forward 1` at a time, you should "draw" the color on the patch.

```
turtles-own [ my-color ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10 [ 
    set my-color color ; the turtles will have random colors, store them to use later
    set color white ; but they're easier to see if they're white
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go 
  ask one-of turtles [
    left (random 50) - 25 ; wiggle a bit to not just go in a straight line
    let d (random 10) + 1 ; the turtle will move 1 to 10 steps
    repeat d [
      forward 1
      set pcolor my-color ; the turtle can directly set the patch's pcolor variable to its own
    ]
  ]

  tick
end
```

You can either use `setup` and `go` from the command center or add buttons for them.

Comment: Thank you so much, Jasper !

Comment: Your solution works exactely the way I have dreamed of. And furthermore - I appreciate your good advice. I realize that it is much easier for the helpful helpers to actualy make progress in the right direction, if they have a bit of coding as far as one can get. I´ll remember that in future logins. I´m (as you have guessed) new to Netlogo, and my son who is far more skilled in algorithmic thinking than I am, have recomended Stack Overflow. Combined with small videos on youtube - one can manage to steer their way into the wilderness